# How to write DateTime.current in WHERE clause of Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

In one of my models I have a column called **started** which is a DateTime, and I want to be able to write a class method that would return the records which difference between `DateTime.current` and **started** column is bigger than N seconds.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def self.elapsed_started_bigger_than(sec = 10)
  where('started IS NOT NULL').
  where( ((DateTime.current - started) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i > sec) # This is what I don't know how to write
end
```

Ideally this should be database engine agnostic, even though right now I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a scope and write it like this

`scope :started, where('started IS NOT NULL')`

`scope :elapsed_since, Proc.new {|sec| where("NOW() - started > ?", sec.seconds)}`

Use it like this

`model.started.elapsed_since(10)`

**EDIT**

Mysql

`
mysql> select NOW() - 10;

+-----------------------+

| NOW() - 10            |

+-----------------------+

| 20140707200211.000000 |

+-----------------------+

mysql> select NOW() - "10";

+----------------+

| NOW() - "10"   |

+----------------+

| 20140707200223 |

+----------------+

`

Comment: Rafal, this is not doing the difference between ```DateTime.current - started``` Also, the sec argument is already in seconds.

Comment: ```NOW() - started``` is not going to be in seconds, and I need that difference in seconds.

Comment: mysql converts it to seconds if there is an operation done on it.